# Where do you put installed stuff on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, installation

Packages installed with synaptic are usually well installed on your system (i.e. bin in /usr/bin/, etc.). However, when a software is not in the repo, I always wonder where I should install it, when everything comes together (i.e. /bin, /var, /man are all subfolders of the main folder of the software).

For now, I've opted for /var/opt/ or /usr/share, but I'm not really sure this is a best practice... is there any guidelines on that?

Answer (score 4):

The usual location us `/usr/local` or `/opt`. From the [Linux Directory Hierarchy](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/fhs.html):

> `/usr/local, /opt`
>
> These are obsolete folders. When UNIX didn't have a package system (like RPM), sysadmins needed to separate an optional (or local) Software from the main OS. These were the directories used for that.

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/local` is intended for this

Have a look at checkinstall: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall

```
sudo checkinstall make install
```

It will create (and subsequently) install a .deb package, so you can do a clean removal, or install the same package easily and quickly on other machines (of the same architecture)

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/local/` is my favorite.

You might like to skim the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) -- keeping in mind that it is a bit dated, and it was never *proscriptive*, instead *descriptive* of common practice. That said, it's still worth a read.

`/opt/` is another common choice. I don't like it. It feels funny. You might find it fine. `/var/opt/` feels outright wrong -- `/var/` is a home for *data*, not binaries.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a (more or less) authoritative guideline where to place files on Linux systems: the [File Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/).

I'd either place the files in `/opt` or in `/usr/local`.

Comment: And man hier of course.

Comment: `hier(7)` is just a very abbreviated version of the FHS.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local` for binaries plus `/var/local` for data is a fine choice. The basic reasoning is that everything in `/usr` is handled by your distribution (i.e. may get removed or overwritten), while everything in `/usr/local` is handled by yourself. Apart from that the two hierarchies are nicely parallel (e.g. you have `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include` etc.), so it's fairly intuitive to navigate.

If you're using autotools, `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` will often give the desired result right out of the box.