# Installing software to /usr/opt/ - needs permission to run the software?

Tags: installation, permissions, chromium

I'm trying to manually update chromium with [Chromium Updater](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-updater/hcmicnfbmcjhlbdohdmdhfjlbigkcddl).

It gives me a chrome-linux.zip.

You can extract that, then run `/.chrome` to run it, it runs fine.

Now the question is - where do I install it?

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/301568/where-do-you-put-installed-stuff-on-ubuntu) suggests using either /usr/opt or /usr/local.

So I can move the folder there using sudo. 
Now to run the software I need to use sudo, other wise I get permission denied.

This seems like the wrong way to be doing things. You shouldn't have to be a superuser to run the software.

Comment: Simplest solution is `sudo chown -R <user> <directory>`, where <user> is your username and <directory> is the chromium directory. The proper way to do it would be to assign the correct permissions - I would say 755, but I don't know if chromium needs write permissions.

Comment: @user55325 - so I go `sudo chown -R dave /usr/opt/bin/chrome-linux/chrome` it accepts that. 

`/usr/opt/bin/chrome-linux/chrome` - permission denied. 

`sudo /usr/opt/bin/chrome-linux/chrome` will work - but will give me a pop error saying 'can't run as root'.

Comment: google "how list all files in package on MYDISTRO" - that is where your browser is installed, unless you installed it manually.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, stick to your distro's package management facilities such as apt, yum, portage. 
Otherwise, make sure that the installed binaries are executable by your target audience:

```
chmod 755 /opt/bin/chrome # this will do the trick.
```

adjust the path of the binary as needed.

Also I think you should consult the documentation of the installer because setting correct permissions is one of its responsibilities. I'm willing to bet Google didn't screw this one up (but you may never know).

***Update***

The easiest way to upgrade your chrome is to download and extract the updater archive to a temporary location and then to copy the files over to the installation folder. The installation folder will vary depending on where the user installed the browser manually or where the distro's package put it. On Gentoo, Chrome lives in /opt/google/chrome. I sucessufully upgraded my copy of chrome from version 21 to 25 using the following commands:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/Linux/168203/chrome-linux.zip 
unzip chrome-linux.zip
rsync -rEp chrome-linux/ /opt/google/chrome/
rm chrome-linux.zip
```

This method assumes that a working copy of chrome is installed and copies all files in the update folder while preserving the permissions executability in the original folder. I suggest you use your package manager to re-install chrome before doing the above as root.

Here is what I see in the about dialog, prior to and after the above steps:

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: There is no installer. It's a zipped folder with an executable /.chrome.

Comment: so put it where it belongs and make it executable. google file permissions unix or `man chmod`.

Comment: `sudo /usr/opt/bin/chrome-linux/chrome` will run the program but then gives me a                                                                                                                                                                                              'cannot run as root' error.


`sudo chmod 755 /usr/opt/bin/chrome-linux/chrome` - works. No message displayed.
now `/usr/opt/bin/chrome-linux/chrome` - Permission denied.

Comment: It usually means that you cannot read some file. When you post an error message, you should include what generated it (copy - paste). It may be the case that the folders where the file is are not readable by your regular user. Try chmod 755 on /usr/opt/chrome-linux

Comment: ^Same problem. `bash: /usr/opt/bin/chrome-linux/chrome: Permission denied
`

Comment: You are not supposed to put folders in the bin folder. When I said "adjust the path of the binary" I meant change the permission of the binary where it was installed originally. Because that is also where you are supposed to unzip the update files. Man, have you never installed a game crack or something? Just copy the files to the installation folder. When you are done, make sure that you have ls -l output similar to this: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 66178144 Sep 24 05:14 /opt/google/chrome/chrome. With this I bid you good luck.